# Command Lines error in Rstudio console

Tags: r, rstudio

how to assign a very long string to a variable in r?

Following works fine

```
testVar <- "test;test;"
```

But the following gives a weird `+` in the RStudio console.

```
testVar <- "test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;"
```

When I hit `Esc` button, and print `testVar`, it prints only `test;test;`

Comment: What do you mean assign to a variable? i.e. `df$var <- testVar`?

Comment: It is working fine for me.  Have u waited for some time before hitting the enter?

Comment: @d.b what did you do? Although I think akrun is right...too fast ENTER pushing

Comment: @Sotos, copy the second line of code and run it in R. It also happens with any long string: `x = "VERY LONG STRING"`

Comment: @d.b  I also did the same thing and it is working fine. `nchar(testVar)
#[1] 11760`

Comment: Ah ok. I see it now

Comment: Yes. it is possible to assign a long string programmatically. but when it is hard coded as in my example . it is not accepted by r studio

Comment: Ah right, RStudio -- answered.

Comment: Related to http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Command-line-length-limits-in-R-td912367.html?

Comment: Just confirmed that this runs on MS R Open 3.2.5 with the R GUI in Windows 7, but it hangs with rstudio.

Comment: _"Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes (not characters)."_ https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf Section 1.8

Comment: @Aurèle, I'm thinking you should post that as the answer.  Also, that is a great find!!!

Comment: I think it's worth noting if it hasn't been already, that it works fine in a sourced script (even when "hard coded"). Only the REPL seems to be at fault.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In ["An Introduction to R" manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) (`help.start()`), Section 1.8:

> Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes (not characters).
>
> [footnote] *Some of the consoles will not allow you to enter more, and amongst those which do some will silently discard the excess and some will use it as the start of the next line.*

Based on the comments, there does indeed seem to be some variation across consoles in how this is handled. From the OP, we can conclude that RStudio does not allow you to enter more bytes. Currently, [RStudio does not acknowledge or intend to address this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007415008-Limit-length-of-lines-displayed-in-console).

I also found a 2006 conversation in the [R devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-August/038985.html) where Brian D. Ripley explained the issue and the documentation above. It looks like the limit has changed since then (when it was 1024 bytes).

---

It's worth noting that it works fine in a sourced script (even when "hard coded"). Only the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) seems to be at fault.

Comment: It should be noted that the 4095 limit includes the number of bytes needed for the variable name, the assignment operator, spaces, and quotations needed to create the string. E.g. `testVar <- do.call(paste0, as.list(rep("t", 4081)))`. If you were to print `testVar`, copy the output and reassign the copied value ("t" repeated 4081) to `testVar` like so: `testVar <- "tttt.....tt"`, there would be no problems.  However, if you were to add one character, the "+" appears. Note: `nchar("testVar <- ")` returns 11, there are 2 quotations resulting in `4081 + 11 + 2 = 4094` total bytes in the console.