# Assigning a large vector is giving plus sign

Tags: r, vector, limit

I am creating a data frame consisting of a few vectors each of length 744 containing numerical values. The vectors all have less than 4 digit numbers in each value and are created successfully, but the one vector that has 6 digit values does not run and R gets hung up with the '+' sign as opposed to the '>'.

I have checked to make sure the parentheses, commas, etc are all proper and they are. I have also tried to shorten the number of values and it seems that I can make a vector with these 6 digit values up to a length of around 500.

Is this related to some sort of limitation in R. How can I get around this?

Below is the vector I am attempting to create.

```
"pressure" <- c(102279,102230,102151,102102,102049,102024,101984,101978,101971,101941,101859,101764,101683,101647,101613,101567,101548,101540,101532,101520,101484,101442,101396,101346,101299,101261,101205,101154,101116,101102,101136,101162,101172,101172,101172,101069,101085,101113,101110,101114,101144,101199,101271,101332,101367,101424,101452,101472,101516,101577,101576,101599,101609,101615,101592,101592,101588,101564,101498,101459,101420,101386,101347,101309,101254,101172,101091,101009,100936,100839,100700,100536,100416,100313,100168,100051,99959,99893,99820,99782,99770,99747,99685,99617,99561,99527,99508,99495,99452,99451,99512,99592,99681,99813,99918,100007,100080,100178,100216,100276,100362,100483,100665,100855,101053,101248,101372,101465,101559,101659,101798,101911,102030,102122,102215,102308,102386,102458,102528,102594,102666,102700,102769,102807,102849,102903,102987,103069,103086,103086,103086,103072,103100,103136,103187,103208,103236,103267,103286,103290,103279,103300,103315,103318,103293,103279,103242,103233,103233,103251,103256,103252,103218,103225,103160,103085,103024,102987,102942,102913,102885,102857,102809,102771,102727,102699,102653,102623,102568,102549,102537,102511,102517,102534,102577,102612,102660,102692,102672,102624,102608,102620,102639,102656,102663,102680,102691,102682,102663,102656,102603,102576,102555,102542,102547,102566,102549,102542,102562,102580,102544,102500,102488,102468,102432,102400,102374,102354,102351,102358,102321,102261,102231,102217,102180,102124,102053,102007,101985,101941,101909,101906,101910,101919,101901,101882,101823,101786,101713,101696,101719,101743,101789,101830,101843,101897,101885,101890,101904,101914,101940,102004,101987,101983,101953,101904,101867,101844,101839,101760,101615,101538,101434,101334,101212,101115,101010,100888,100759,100636,100471,100340,100292,100290,100244,100195,100189,100189,100193,100224,100273,100332,100377,100464,100525,100546,100557,100597,100610,100667,100691,100697,100684,100660,100620,100556,100450,100351,100198,100009,99817,99687,99575,99486,99429,99435,99482,99426,99411,99395,99405,99387,99379,99431,99445,99443,99441,99436,99437,99473,99492,99495,99515,99578,99597,99625,99645,99651,99721,99772,99809,99864,99912,99924,99958,100013,100077,100142,100201,100281,100356,100422,100497,100577,100628,100706,100783,100839,100866,100892,100922,100968,101044,101121,101178,101221,101248,101278,101305,101346,101385,101423,101469,101495,101525,101535,101550,101577,101605,101623,101636,101640,101635,101641,101655,101697,101755,101819,101867,101914,101912,101897,101916,101948,101995,102041,102095,102156,102214,102274,102333,102376,102411,102457,102511,102549,102583,102612,102648,102706,102775,102852,102914,102952,102970,103001,103020,103050,103084,103127,103194,103246,103296,103327,103353,103390,103405,103428,103467,103474,103497,103490,103491,103537,103588,103647,103694,103726,103709,103691,103675,103689,103710,103730,103732,103749,103756,103751,103737,103729,103706,103671,103656,103671,103670,103656,103607,103591,103623,103637,103655,103648,103637,103599,103580,103552,103525,103480,103464,103478,103484,103489,103498,103481,103453,103406,103392,103385,103351,103317,103303,103285,103299,103306,103297,103305,103268,103223,103171,103157,103140,103127,103114,103106,103099,103075,103074,103067,103059,103061,103061,103029,102989,102989,102995,103001,103039,103054,103073,103098,103086,103051,103008,102991,102984,103009,103048,103072,103086,103102,103124,103149,103158,103144,103142,103132,103117,103093,103056,103054,103070,103092,103103,103107,103059,102994,102946,102917,102897,102883,102872,102854,102814,102798,102783,102766,102744,102702,102666,102644,102607,102572,102517,102505,102492,102473,102464,102412,102359,102284,102213,102174,102143,102129,102136,102130,102139,102154,102209,102200,102198,102208,102218,102218,102216,102224,102199,102201,102239,102303,102364,102399,102401,102394,102408,102427,102442,102479,102534,102534,102551,102581,102597,102608,102630,102620,102637,102626,102642,102650,102643,102652,102665,102691,102741,102773,102757,102745,102720,102726,102767,102833,102864,102866,102871,102918,102943,102953,102982,103002,103034,103044,103061,103073,103080,103103,103130,103159,103211,103251,103221,103180,103132,103106,103074,103051,103050,103053,103044,103020,102999,102988,102988,102980,102936,102862,102807,102782,102758,102721,102709,102707,102714,102710,102658,102576,102496,102456,102437,102445,102474,102477,102469,102456,102411,102386,102374,102346,102339,102328,102322,102295,102284,102297,102304,102288,102292,102288,102245,102191,102146,102153,102157,102166,102188,102185,102184,102187,102213,102237,102261,102275,102256,102245,102266,102276,102282,102324,102370,102400,102412,102414,102402,102351,102312,102296,102303,102316,102318,102319,102309,102313,102334,102320,102303,102272,102232,102208,102199,102187,102180,102181,102190,102186,102174,102127,102089,102004,101943,101908,101873,101856,101846,101825,101813,101798,101755,101742,101745,101746,101746,101755,101745,101753,101755,101752,101748,101737,101752,101760,101717,101687,101675,101708,101717,101691,101723,101729,101753,101759,101787,101808,101845,101864)
```

I have tried this on both Rstudio cloud as well as RStudio desktop v1.2

Comment: You need to split the code so it's across multiple lines instead of all on a single one.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.
But why does this happen exactly?

Comment: I think this might be the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617052/command-lines-error-in-rstudio-console as you have 5171 characters in your vector you are trying to enter but R's limit at the console is 4095 bytes. This was surprisingly hard to find the right terms to search for to find the duplicate question though.

Comment: That's exactly it. I'm surprised that question did not come up in my searches, but I appreciate the help!!