# Unable to create a lengthy and huge list of 20K numbers in R

Tags: r

I have to create a list of numbers in R.

But the thing is I have more than 20K numbers in a notepad file like shown below

[image: sample here]

When I wish to create a list of numbers like this using `c()`, I get a syntax error in RStudio

```
c(19122121,3037110,3037187,3004410,40762352,783432) # This works fine for smaller list of numbers
```

But when I add all the 20K+ numbers in to the list like below

```
c(19122121,3037110,3037187,3004410,40762352,783432......2000000001), I get a syntax error in RStudio
```

[image]

As you can see the list is **already closed with brackets**, but it still shows `+` sign

When I again **type another closing bracket** `)` R console displays the vector like shown below but it doesn't display all the numbers. But why do I have to type another bracket? Clearly the issue here isn't wrt to commas. Right?

[image: e]

How can I avoid this error, can you please help me? I need to send this list of 20K+ numbers to a function as a value for parameter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617732/6197649

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with you text being too large to fit into buffers (see [Command Lines error in Rstudio console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617052/command-lines-error-in-rstudio-console/45617732#45617732) (as pointed out by Aurèle))

In case of such a large number of numbers, it is more practical to store the data in a file and read that file from R. It it is a file with comma separated numbers you can use `scan`:

```
x <- scan("myfile.txt", sep = ",")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Will try and update the answer

Comment: So frustrating. I have a list of 500 7-digit numbers. Seems like an unnecessary pain when trying to prototype quickly to save out a file just to read it :(