# How to store numbers in R (very very basic)

Tags: r, object, vector

I am sorry for this basic question:

I have 1008 individual numbers that I would like to store in a single vector in R. Somehow this does not seem to be possible. The maximum seems to be 666 numbers. However I can split it in two objects and then combine them to get the object with 1008 elements. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

not working code:
`a <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 69, 71, 109, 113, 114, 115, 117, 134, 147, 148, 166, 173, 174, 175, 182, 184, 193, 199, 202, 208, 209, 217, 219, 232, 280, 288, 309, 321, 323, 331, 332, 338, 344, 357, 375, 378, 385, 386, 390, 398, 401, 406, 432, 433, 435, 450, 459, 460, 470, 476, 480, 482, 485, 525, 528, 529, 535, 549, 558, 596, 599, 604, 605, 614, 617, 619, 621, 622, 623, 626, 638, 640, 726, 741, 766, 770, 778, 779, 785, 799, 804, 813, 835, 837, 838, 861, 878, 888, 894, 898, 900, 905, 907, 912, 913, 914, 919, 920, 925, 926, 929, 930, 932, 958, 960, 961, 963, 968, 969, 990, 1014, 1023, 1031, 1078, 1080, 1082, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1096, 1099, 1101, 1104, 1108, 1111, 1113, 1114, 1119, 1120, 1132, 1164, 1166, 1167, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1178, 1179, 1184, 1191, 1208, 1219, 1226, 1243, 1255, 1298, 1303, 1307, 1308, 1309, 1316, 1331, 1339, 1340, 1343, 1344, 1346, 1353, 1374, 1376, 1377, 1380, 1416, 1418, 1419, 1421, 1424, 1428, 1432, 1435, 1461, 1464, 1483, 1484, 1485, 1486, 1487, 1489, 1501, 1503, 1507, 1510, 1513, 1516, 1517, 1519, 1539, 1573, 1579, 1588, 1592, 1594, 1605, 1606, 1629, 1632, 1648, 1664, 1667, 1680, 1682, 1765, 1768, 1769, 1781, 1782, 1783, 1790, 1840, 1841, 1843, 1847, 1851, 1854, 1855, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1866, 1867, 1885, 1886, 1887, 1888, 1889, 1890, 1902, 1903, 1905, 1906, 1922, 1923, 1942, 1943, 1944, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2071, 2072, 2127, 2128, 2131, 2132, 2136, 2137, 2138, 2139, 2140, 2141, 2142, 2143, 2145, 2169, 2198, 2224, 2238, 2239, 2247, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2261, 2262, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2295, 2296, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2304, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2319, 2320, 2323, 2324, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2331, 2332, 2356, 2358, 2359, 2362, 2390, 2393, 2394, 2396, 2397, 2401, 2402, 2403, 2405, 2406, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2419, 2423, 2427, 2429, 2430, 2497, 2500, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2519, 2535, 2548, 2555, 2558, 2559, 2562, 2563, 2565, 2587, 2588, 2612, 2615, 2616, 2897, 2900, 2904, 2906, 2909, 2916, 2920, 2923, 2925, 2926, 2927, 2928, 2932, 2933, 2934, 2937, 2938, 2939, 2940, 2941, 2948, 2952, 2990, 2991, 2992, 2993, 2995, 2998, 2999, 3000, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3030, 3031, 3032, 3034, 3132, 3135, 3138, 3140, 3143, 3146, 3151, 3313, 3320, 3321, 3322, 3323, 3324, 3325, 3326, 3342, 3343, 3344, 3346, 3347, 3352, 3353, 3354, 3355, 3356, 3357, 3358, 3359, 3360, 3361, 3362, 3370, 3375, 3376, 3377, 3378, 3379, 3380, 3381, 3382, 3383, 3384, 3389, 3391, 3417, 3418, 3419, 3421, 3423, 3424, 3425, 3426, 3427, 3429, 3470, 3471, 3472, 3473, 3474, 3475, 3476, 3480, 3488, 3489, 3490, 3492, 3493, 3494, 3495, 3496, 3497, 3498, 3499, 3502, 3503, 3504, 3505, 3506, 3507, 3508, 3517, 3520, 3522, 3527, 3528, 3529, 3530, 3531, 3532, 3533, 3534, 3535, 3536, 3540, 3601, 3628, 3630, 3631, 3632, 3633, 3634, 3635, 3637, 3638, 3639, 3640, 3641, 3642, 3643, 3665, 3668, 3671, 3672, 3673, 3674, 3676, 3677, 3678, 3679, 3681, 3688, 3689, 3690, 3691, 3723, 3725, 3726, 3727, 3775, 3776, 3777, 3778, 3780, 3781, 3782, 3783, 3784, 3785, 3786, 3788, 3789, 3857, 3858, 3859, 3860, 3861, 3862, 3863, 3864, 3865, 3866, 3868, 3869, 3872, 3874, 3875, 3876, 3878, 3882, 3895, 3896, 3898, 3899, 3903, 3905, 3906, 3907, 3908, 3913, 3914, 3915, 3916, 3917, 3918, 3919, 3920, 3921, 3922, 3923, 3924, 3925, 3926, 3928, 3929, 3930, 3931, 3933, 3936, 3947, 3948, 3949, 3950, 3952, 3954, 3955, 3956, 3957, 3958, 3970, 3971, 3972, 3974, 3975, 3976, 3977, 3980, 3981, 3982, 3984, 3995, 3997, 4062, 4066, 4067, 4068, 4069, 4072, 4073, 4098, 4099, 4100, 4101, 4102, 4103, 4104, 4106, 4127, 4134, 4135, 4136, 4137, 4138, 4139, 4141, 4142, 4143, 4144, 4175, 4176, 4177, 4178, 4179, 4180, 4181, 4182, 4183, 4185, 4186, 4191, 4193, 4194, 4197, 4198, 4199, 4205, 4207, 4209, 4211, 4212, 4214, 4215, 4216, 4217, 4218, 4219, 4220, 4224, 4225, 4226, 4232, 4233, 4234, 4235, 4237, 4238, 4239, 4240, 4241, 4242, 4243, 4244, 4245, 4246, 4248, 4251, 4252, 4253, 4254, 4256, 4257, 4258, 4259, 4260, 4261, 4263, 4264, 4265, 4266, 4268, 4269, 4270, 4271, 4272, 4275, 4276, 4277, 4278, 4283, 4284, 4285, 4286, 4290, 4291, 4293, 4310, 4311, 4313, 4317, 4325, 4349, 4350, 4352, 4354, 4355, 4356, 4359, 4360, 4365, 4366, 4367, 4369, 4370, 4373, 4379, 4380, 4381, 4383, 4384, 4386, 4387, 4388, 4390, 4391, 4393, 4394, 4395, 4396, 4398, 4399, 4401, 4428, 4430, 4431, 4432, 4434, 4436, 4440, 4443, 4445, 4446, 4447, 4448, 4455, 4456, 4458, 4459, 4460, 4462, 4465, 4466, 4467, 4469, 4471, 4472, 4473, 4476, 4477, 4478, 4479, 4480, 4481, 4482, 4483, 4484, 4485, 4498, 4499, 4500, 4501, 4502, 4509, 4510, 4511, 4514, 4525, 4526, 4528, 4529, 4530, 4537, 4540, 4541, 4542, 4543, 4544, 4545, 4546, 4549, 4551, 4552, 4553, 4554, 4555, 4556, 4557, 4558, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4581, 4582, 4583, 4584, 4585, 4586, 4587, 4589, 4590, 4591, 4592, 4593, 4594, 4607, 4608, 4609, 4610, 4611, 4612, 4613, 4624, 4625, 4627, 4628, 4630, 4633, 4634, 4638, 4641, 4642, 4643, 4644, 4645, 4646, 4648, 4649, 4650, 4651, 4652, 4653, 4654, 4655, 4656, 4657, 4658, 4659, 4661, 4662, 4663, 4664, 4668, 4669, 4670, 4671, 4672, 4673, 4716, 4717, 4734, 4735, 4736, 4738, 4739, 4741, 4742, 4743, 4746, 4747, 4765, 4767, 4768, 4769, 4770, 4777, 4778, 4779, 4781, 4782, 4783, 4784, 4788, 4789, 4790, 4791, 4792, 4795, 4796, 4799, 4800, 4801, 4802, 4803, 4804, 4805, 4806, 4807, 4808, 4809, 4810, 4811, 4812, 4813, 4814, 4816, 4828, 4829, 4830, 4831, 4832, 4833, 4835, 4836, 4837, 4838, 4839, 4840, 4842, 4854, 4856, 4857, 4858, 4859, 4862, 4863, 4864, 4865, 4867, 4868, 4870, 4873, 4875, 4877, 4880, 4881, 4883)`

working code:
`a <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 69, 71, 109, 113, 114, 115, 117, 134, 147, 148, 166, 173, 174, 175, 182, 184, 193, 199, 202, 208, 209, 217, 219, 232, 280, 288, 309, 321, 323, 331, 332, 338, 344, 357, 375, 378, 385, 386, 390, 398, 401, 406, 432, 433, 435, 450, 459, 460, 470, 476, 480, 482, 485, 525, 528, 529, 535, 549, 558, 596, 599, 604, 605, 614, 617, 619, 621, 622, 623, 626, 638, 640, 726, 741, 766, 770, 778, 779, 785, 799, 804, 813, 835, 837, 838, 861, 878, 888, 894, 898, 900, 905, 907, 912, 913, 914, 919, 920, 925, 926, 929, 930, 932, 958, 960, 961, 963, 968, 969, 990, 1014, 1023, 1031, 1078, 1080, 1082, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1096, 1099, 1101, 1104, 1108, 1111, 1113, 1114, 1119, 1120, 1132, 1164, 1166, 1167, 1171, 1172, 1173, 1174, 1175, 1178, 1179, 1184, 1191, 1208, 1219, 1226, 1243, 1255, 1298, 1303, 1307, 1308, 1309, 1316, 1331, 1339, 1340, 1343, 1344, 1346, 1353, 1374, 1376, 1377, 1380, 1416, 1418, 1419, 1421, 1424, 1428, 1432, 1435, 1461, 1464, 1483, 1484, 1485, 1486, 1487, 1489, 1501, 1503, 1507, 1510, 1513, 1516, 1517, 1519, 1539, 1573, 1579, 1588, 1592, 1594, 1605, 1606, 1629, 1632, 1648, 1664, 1667, 1680, 1682, 1765, 1768, 1769, 1781, 1782, 1783, 1790, 1840, 1841, 1843, 1847, 1851, 1854, 1855, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1866, 1867, 1885, 1886, 1887, 1888, 1889, 1890, 1902, 1903, 1905, 1906, 1922, 1923, 1942, 1943, 1944, 2062, 2063, 2064, 2065, 2071, 2072, 2127, 2128, 2131, 2132, 2136, 2137, 2138, 2139, 2140, 2141, 2142, 2143, 2145, 2169, 2198, 2224, 2238, 2239, 2247, 2253, 2254, 2255, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2261, 2262, 2272, 2273, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2295, 2296, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2304, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2319, 2320, 2323, 2324, 2325, 2326, 2327, 2328, 2329, 2331, 2332, 2356, 2358, 2359, 2362, 2390, 2393, 2394, 2396, 2397, 2401, 2402, 2403, 2405, 2406, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2419, 2423, 2427, 2429, 2430, 2497, 2500, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2519, 2535, 2548, 2555, 2558, 2559, 2562, 2563, 2565, 2587, 2588, 2612, 2615, 2616, 2897, 2900, 2904, 2906, 2909, 2916, 2920, 2923, 2925, 2926, 2927, 2928, 2932, 2933, 2934, 2937, 2938, 2939, 2940, 2941, 2948, 2952, 2990, 2991, 2992, 2993, 2995, 2998, 2999, 3000, 3002, 3003, 3004, 3030, 3031, 3032, 3034, 3132, 3135, 3138, 3140, 3143, 3146, 3151, 3313, 3320, 3321, 3322, 3323, 3324, 3325, 3326, 3342, 3343, 3344, 3346, 3347, 3352, 3353, 3354, 3355, 3356, 3357, 3358, 3359, 3360, 3361, 3362, 3370, 3375, 3376, 3377, 3378, 3379, 3380, 3381, 3382, 3383, 3384, 3389, 3391, 3417, 3418, 3419, 3421, 3423, 3424, 3425, 3426, 3427, 3429, 3470, 3471, 3472, 3473, 3474, 3475, 3476, 3480, 3488, 3489, 3490, 3492, 3493, 3494, 3495, 3496, 3497, 3498, 3499, 3502, 3503, 3504, 3505, 3506, 3507, 3508, 3517, 3520, 3522, 3527, 3528, 3529, 3530, 3531, 3532, 3533, 3534, 3535, 3536, 3540, 3601, 3628, 3630, 3631, 3632, 3633, 3634, 3635, 3637, 3638, 3639, 3640, 3641, 3642, 3643, 3665, 3668, 3671, 3672, 3673, 3674, 3676, 3677, 3678, 3679, 3681, 3688, 3689, 3690, 3691, 3723, 3725, 3726, 3727, 3775, 3776, 3777, 3778, 3780, 3781, 3782, 3783, 3784, 3785, 3786, 3788, 3789, 3857, 3858, 3859, 3860, 3861, 3862, 3863, 3864, 3865, 3866, 3868, 3869, 3872, 3874, 3875, 3876, 3878, 3882, 3895, 3896, 3898, 3899, 3903, 3905, 3906, 3907, 3908, 3913, 3914, 3915, 3916, 3917, 3918, 3919, 3920, 3921, 3922, 3923, 3924, 3925, 3926, 3928, 3929, 3930, 3931, 3933, 3936, 3947, 3948, 3949, 3950, 3952, 3954, 3955, 3956, 3957, 3958, 3970, 3971, 3972, 3974, 3975, 3976, 3977, 3980, 3981, 3982, 3984, 3995, 3997, 4062, 4066, 4067, 4068, 4069, 4072, 4073, 4098, 4099, 4100, 4101)`

`b <- c(4102, 4103, 4104, 4106, 4127, 4134, 4135, 4136, 4137, 4138, 4139, 4141, 4142, 4143, 4144, 4175, 4176, 4177, 4178, 4179, 4180, 4181, 4182, 4183, 4185, 4186, 4191, 4193, 4194, 4197, 4198, 4199, 4205, 4207, 4209, 4211, 4212, 4214, 4215, 4216, 4217, 4218, 4219, 4220, 4224, 4225, 4226, 4232, 4233, 4234, 4235, 4237, 4238, 4239, 4240, 4241, 4242, 4243, 4244, 4245, 4246, 4248, 4251, 4252, 4253, 4254, 4256, 4257, 4258, 4259, 4260, 4261, 4263, 4264, 4265, 4266, 4268, 4269, 4270, 4271, 4272, 4275, 4276, 4277, 4278, 4283, 4284, 4285, 4286, 4290, 4291, 4293, 4310, 4311, 4313, 4317, 4325, 4349, 4350, 4352, 4354, 4355, 4356, 4359, 4360, 4365, 4366, 4367, 4369, 4370, 4373, 4379, 4380, 4381, 4383, 4384, 4386, 4387, 4388, 4390, 4391, 4393, 4394, 4395, 4396, 4398, 4399, 4401, 4428, 4430, 4431, 4432, 4434, 4436, 4440, 4443, 4445, 4446, 4447, 4448, 4455, 4456, 4458, 4459, 4460, 4462, 4465, 4466, 4467, 4469, 4471, 4472, 4473, 4476, 4477, 4478, 4479, 4480, 4481, 4482, 4483, 4484, 4485, 4498, 4499, 4500, 4501, 4502, 4509, 4510, 4511, 4514, 4525, 4526, 4528, 4529, 4530, 4537, 4540, 4541, 4542, 4543, 4544, 4545, 4546, 4549, 4551, 4552, 4553, 4554, 4555, 4556, 4557, 4558, 4560, 4561, 4562, 4563, 4564, 4565, 4566, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4577, 4578, 4579, 4581, 4582, 4583, 4584, 4585, 4586, 4587, 4589, 4590, 4591, 4592, 4593, 4594, 4607, 4608, 4609, 4610, 4611, 4612, 4613, 4624, 4625, 4627, 4628, 4630, 4633, 4634, 4638, 4641, 4642, 4643, 4644, 4645, 4646, 4648, 4649, 4650, 4651, 4652, 4653, 4654, 4655, 4656, 4657, 4658, 4659, 4661, 4662, 4663, 4664, 4668, 4669, 4670, 4671, 4672, 4673, 4716, 4717, 4734, 4735, 4736, 4738, 4739, 4741, 4742, 4743, 4746, 4747, 4765, 4767, 4768, 4769, 4770, 4777, 4778, 4779, 4781, 4782, 4783, 4784, 4788, 4789, 4790, 4791, 4792, 4795, 4796, 4799, 4800, 4801, 4802, 4803, 4804, 4805, 4806, 4807, 4808, 4809, 4810, 4811, 4812, 4813, 4814, 4816, 4828, 4829, 4830, 4831, 4832, 4833, 4835, 4836, 4837, 4838, 4839, 4840, 4842, 4854, 4856, 4857, 4858, 4859, 4862, 4863, 4864, 4865, 4867, 4868, 4870, 4873, 4875, 4877, 4880, 4881, 4883)`

`c <- c(a,b)`

I know there are a million easier solutions for this (already have it), but I would like to have an understanding as to why it was not possible to store this amount of elements.

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is a [limit for the length of a command in the R console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617732/2094893).

Comment: However, you don't have to input that vector on a single line.

Comment: @RobertHacken, please post as answer (or mark this as a duplicate)

Comment: a<-c(1:1008) should work?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this answers this. It is RStudio that limits the information that you can give in the command line